# Oracle Select Syntax into Postgres

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql

I am converting Oracle Syntax into Postgres

```
SELECT MSN_INT_ID,
       MO_INT_ID,
       'Y'   "AIRMOVE"
  FROM MISSION_OBJECTIVE
 WHERE MO_MSN_CLASS_CD = 'AMV'
 GROUP BY MSN_INT_ID,
          MO_INT_ID
```

This part is confusing me:

```
SELECT MSN_INT_ID,
       MO_INT_ID,
       'Y'   "AIRMOVE"
```

What is the 'Y' "AIRMOVE" doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet `'Y' "AIRMOVE"` introduces a computed column into the select-list named `AIRMOVE` whose value is always `'Y'`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a computed column, using a statically defined value.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the confusion may be coming from PostgreSQL 8.3 or earlier, where the "AS" keyword is not optional.

Change:

```
'Y'   "AIRMOVE"
```

To:

```
'Y' AS "AIRMOVE"
```

And it should work fine.  The keyword is optional starting in version 8.4, although I advocate always including it to avoid issues exactly like this one.